# НОК, НОД в списке Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, математика

Как найти НОК или НОД в python 3.9 в списке из n кол-ва чисел? (Ввод чисел пользователем)
(н: math.gcd([1 , 2 , 3])

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Не понимаю... Если вы знаете про gcd, то в чём тогда вопрос состоит?

Comment: Если я хочу найти нод в списке(print(m.gcd([1,2,3]))- выдаёт ошибку: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: `HOx(a,b,c) = HOx(HOx(a,b),c)`. Вот и итерируй попарненько, пока список не кончится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

список из нескольких чисел можно получить следующим образом:

```
data = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

весь код таким образом будет выглядеть так:

```
import math

data = list(map(int, input().split()))

gcd = math.gcd(*data)
lcm = math.lcm(*data)

print(gcd, lcm)
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение!

Answer (score 1):

```
print ('a = ', end = '')

a = int (input ())

print ('b = ', end = '')

b = int (input ())

p = a * b

while a != 0 and b != 0:

    if a > b:

        a = a % b

    else:

        b = b % a

nod = a + b

nok = p // nod

print ('GCD:', nok)
print ('LDM:', nod)
```

Comment: Нужно не 2 числа, а несколько (2 и более, введённых пользователем)

Comment: Прочитай про итерацию в Python3 переменным a и b ты можешь задать несколько чисел.